# How do I get rid of reversed tuples in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

For example, let's say I have a list:

```
list_ = [(4,5),(5,4),(5,4),(8,10),(10,8),(9,3),(5,4),(10,8),(8,8)]
```

How do I get rid of all reversed tuples, so what's left is:

```
list_ = [(4,5),(8,10),(9,3),(8,8)]
```

?

this is for a personal project I'm doing it, and I wrote something that detects reversed tuples and deletes them, but only deletes one of the reversed tuples (rather than all of them). I think a dictionary would be useful here, but not sure how to go about implementing it

Comment: How is decided whether (4,5) or (5,4) is kept?

Comment: Well, that depends. So you would want to keep the tuple with the low value in the first slot? What about tuples like `(4,4)`?

Answer (score 4):

#### Tuples of length 2

For tuples all of length 2, you can use `frozenset` with the [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) available in the docs, also featured in [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) and [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique) 3rd party libraries:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

list_ = [(4,5),(5,4),(5,4),(8,10),(10,8),(9,3),(5,4),(10,8),(8,8)]

res = list(unique_everseen(list_, key=frozenset))

[(4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 3), (8, 8)]
```

[`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) is an unordered but hashable collection of unique items. The solution assumes your inputs all have length 2. So it won't differentiate between `(8,)` and `(8, 8)`.

#### Tuples of variable length

For tuples of different lengths, you can make a small adjustment to the recipe:

```
def unique_everseen_custom(it):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    for tup in it:
        if (tup not in seen) and (tup[::-1] not in seen):
            seen_add(tup)
            yield tup
        
res = list(unique_everseen_custom(list_))
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Thanks, I've added a disclaimer. It's not clear whether the singleton tuple case is relevant (it may well be, and in this case `tuple` + `sorted` works).

Comment: i mislead you, sorry, sorting is also wrong for >2 element tuples, e.g. (1,2,3) and (1,3,2) are not palindrones

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Yup, reread the question and you're right, you can just adjust the recipe trivially I believe, have updated accordingly. Your solution is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

If we consider that all your tuples are duplets and that you want to keep unique values:

```
list_ = [(4,5),(5,4),(5,4),(8,10),(10,8),(3,9),(5,4)]
```

We then sort the tuples:

```
list_ = [tuple(sorted(t)) for t in list_]
```

And then use a set to remove the duplicates:

```
list_ = list(set(list_))
```

Comment: You're missing `[` when you're sorting `list_`

Comment: What if you have another tuple, say for eg `(6,5)`, in the list?

Comment: Thanks for the typo notice ([) and the sorted, forgot that one.

Comment: Now you will find `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: The possibly larger issue is is that you don't preserve the order of either the tuples or the list as a whole

Comment: Indeed, forgot to check the result type.

Comment: @Chris_Rands That's true indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I would write a good old fashioned `for` loop. This solution guarantees the following: the first of any reversed tuples is kept, the output list is the same order as the input, makes no assumptions about the input tuple lengths.

```
list_ = [(4,5),(5,4),(5,4),(8,10),(10,8),(9,3),(5,4),(10,8),(8,8)]

output, seen = [], set()
for item in list_:
    t1 = tuple(item)
    if t1 not in seen and tuple(reversed(item)) not in seen:
        seen.add(t1)
        output.append(item)

print(output)
# [(4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 3), (8, 8)]
```

Comment: Loop-based approaches like this one that properly display the algorithm at hand are underrepresented at SO and often get lost among the fancy one-liners despite being very useful to the learner. Have a rec!